# Notation of Hyperplane

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I have a notation I don't quite understand. A hyperplane defined by
$$ H:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i = c \}(i=1,\dots,n)$$
I guess it is $x = ( x_1, ..., x_n)$. But I am confused whether it means at least one $x_i = c$ of $x$ or every $x_i = c$.
The second option doesnt make any sense to me, because there would be only $x = (c,...,c) \in H$. This isnt even a plane.

I cant see how the first option is a hyperplane. I only know the definition as
$$ H:= \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x=p+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} s_i u_i \text{ and } s_1,\dots,s_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
with $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$ linear independent.

Comment: $H$ is the set of points $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_i=c$ where $i$ and $c$ are fixed beforehand. For example, let's say $n=2$, then the set of points whose second coordinarte equals $3$, i.e points of the form $(x,3)$, is an horizontal line, and, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, horizontal lines are hyperplanes. You can generalize this pretty easily.

Comment: Only one $x_i$ is fixed in an hyperplane. Indeed, if you are in a vector space $x_i=c=0$ because an hyperplane is a vector subspace and it contains 0. To see how this links to the definition think about expressing every point as a linear combination of $x_j$ with $j$ from 1 to n. What happens if you substitute $x_i$ by a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition works, though it doesn't capture all possible hyperplanes.
We can take a low-dimensional example to see this: Say we look at $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid y = 1\}$ -- this defines the hyperplane (or line, in this case) parallel to the $x$-axis at $y = 1$.

More formally, a hyperplane $H_{i, c} = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x_i = c\}$ for some $i \in [1, n]$ is the hyperplane spanned e.g. by the unit vectors perpendicular to the $i$-th one where the $i$-th coordinate is fixed to $c$, i.e. we have
$$H_{i, c} = \left\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x = c \cdot e_i + \sum_{j \neq i} a_j e_j \text{ with } a_j \in \mathbb R \text{ for all } j \neq i\right\}$$
where $e_k$ denotes the $k$-th unit vector.